Recreating results from Research Paper
so I have been trying to recreate the results from this particular paper (Neural Collaborative Filtering).
The dataset I use closely resembles this .
I understand that I should my data into train and testing sets.
The question I have is whether or not I should create the test.negative file myself or if it is automatically handled by negative sampling inside the code (which basically contains the negative feedback based on the absence of data).
I would really appreciate your feedback! Thanks in advance.
Here is the official implementation of this paper on github.

You should learn to generate the negative samples yourself because you may want to change the sampling ratio to your liking in the future. The original NeuMF paper has a recommended sampling ratio, but it will differ depending on data and how exactly you define the model.
